# Can someone help in applying covariance condition to this unitary transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am trying to apply covariance property on this Quantum adder transformation in which a two particle input state is mapped onto a two particle output state. I am trying to represent these states into a bloch sphere density operator and apply the covariance condition to the same. I don't know how to work around the same.

$$U \lvert\Psi_1 \rangle\lvert \Psi_2 \rangle \propto
\left( \lvert \Psi_1 \rangle + \lvert \Psi_2 \rangle \right)
\lvert \chi \rangle$$

Comment: what do you mean with "covariance property"? Can you add some context and references?

Comment: @glS You can get to know about the covariance condition here in this paper : (https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9801005.pdf)